# Subir fichero al servidor vía FTP mediante un .bat

Tags: servidor

Tengo que subir un fichero al servidor cada 1 hora, con las tareas programadas me encargo de que el subir.bat se ejecute cada una hora. El problema esta que no esta subiendo el fichero. Les agradecería la ayuda

Fichero subir.bat

```
ftp -s:temp.txt
```

Fichero Temp.txt

```
open ip_server
user usuario
pass password
put "direccion_fichero"
quit
```

Y me devuelve el siguiente error

```
500 OOPS: cannot locate user entry:nobody
Conexión cerrada por el host remoto.
```

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano
Saludos

Comment: El usuario y la contraseña son vacíos en tu archivo bat?

Comment: donde dice user y pass tengo el usuario y la contraseña del ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem was ftp server was not asking from username.
>   To resolve this what i did was I restarted the Ftp server and it started working fine.

Segun este [articulo](https://opensource4admin.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/vsftp-error-500-oops-cannot-locate-user-entrynobody-solved-2/) el problema esta en el servidor FTP, que no esta solicitando el usuario y la solucion es reiniciar el servidor FTP.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con :

```
ftp -n -s:temp.txt
```

y modifica temp.txt para poner user y pass en una misma linea

```
open ip_server
user usuario password
put "direccion_fichero"
quit
```

teniendo en cuenta que el user y pass salen por pantalla habrá que redireccionar la salida onda:

```
ftp -n -s:temp.txt >nul
```