# ¿Como almacenar nombre de carpeta creada en variable para usarla por FTP?

Tags: cmd, batch, ftp

Estoy intentando hacer un script que cree una carpeta con el nombre del día y luego en esa carpeta meter un archivo descargado por ftp

La parte de crear la carpeta está hecha que es lo siguiente:

```
cd..
cd..
cd Carpeta
mkdir %date:~-4,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~-10,2%
```

Como el nombre de la carpeta variará diariamente, tengo que almacenarla en una variable para luego especificarla con el comando lcd de FTP y descargar el archivo ahí. He buscado en Internet, pero no he podido encontrar algo especifico al respecto.

¿Esto es posible de hacer?

Comment: podrías crear un archivo `.txt` y luego pasárselo al ftp con el flag `-s` (script) , algo parecido a lo que se plantea en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152385/81450

Comment: Tal vez tu pregunta puede estar repetida.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25890/c%C3%B3mo-guardar-una-salida-de-comando-bash-en-variable
Lo único que cambiaría sería el formato de fecha que quieres, y para eso puedes hacer algo con `date +'<tu formato de fecha>'`

Answer (score 1):

Para setear una variable en un script bash basta con definirla y asignarle el valor. Ej:

```
carpeta=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
mkdir "$carpeta"
```

luego debes colocar tu rutina para descargar los archivos por ftp. Resuelve esto tu duda?